# C - Why can't I access my server from outside localhost?

Tags: c, sockets, localhost, port

I've been working with socket programming lately; and I'm currently making a server that listens on a port for incoming connections, then once it gets one, reads in a string and places it in a file.

It all works fine when I'm telneting to the running server from localhost, but when I attempt to access it from anywhere else, it acts as though it doesn't exist. Nmap doesn't show that particular open port -- from either the localhost or the remote host. It **only** works through telnet on localhost.

The function's code is [here. (Pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/XJQfi3qW)
I know it's a mess, I'm still pretty unfamiliar with network programming. There really aren't any good in-depth tutorials that show you everything you need to know. I guess I'll have to buy a book...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is calling

```
    if(bind(*sock, b->ai_addr, b->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
```

where `b` is based on the result of calling `getaddrinfo`. This probably doesn't contain exactly what you want. It looks like `cliaddr` already contains the correct data to pass to `bind()`, so use that instead:

```
    if (bind(*sock, (struct sockaddr *)&cliaddr, sizeof(cliaddr)) {
```

I'm not sure what `getaddrinfo()` might return for you, but it sounds from your description like it might be providing the address 127.0.0.1 (which is localhost). If you `bind()` only to the localhost interface, then that's the only address that will respond to request to connect. If you bind to `INADDR_ANY`, then all interfaces will respond to requests for connection.

For a simple socket listening program, you probably don't need the call to `getaddrinfo()` at all.

Comment: It seems I really messed up this code. I changed it to the what you suggested, and several errors came about saying that cliaddr should be a "sockaddr" not a "sockaddr_in", but if I change that, it gets even more messed up.

Comment: Oh, you need a cast. The socket functions are a bit wonky. I've modified my answer.

Comment: Interesting. I do not see any change in behavior for the most part, except that if I Ctrl^C the server while it's running and I'm connected via telnet to it, the telnet session immediately quits.

Comment: Well, that means it's connected. The reading part of your code is now waiting for you to type exactly 130 characters. What happens if you type 130 characters and then press Enter? (The Enter is probably required because by default telnet will line-buffer your input, so your server won't see anything at all until you press Enter.)

Comment: Nothing happens if I type exactly 138 and press enter. However, I did go into the code and change the 138 to 20 to ease the tests a bit.
After doing so, it won't allow me to connect to the server at all, it just rejects it.

Comment: Nevermind, it worked this time. But it still shows the same behavior. Maybe it's time I just scratch this code and rewrite it?

Comment: Ok, *now* you're running into a different issue about reusing the same listening port. Use `int on = 1; setsockopt(*sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on));` before calling `bind`. Look up the meaning of `SO_REUSEADDR` if you're curious what that does.

Comment: I don't think you need to rewrite anything yet. There are a ton of details that you need to get just right for this to work, and you're most of the way there. Consider rewriting if your *design* is wrong, but don't rewrite anything if you're just fixing bugs.

Comment: Alright, I added that. Everything should work fine in regards to rejection now. However, it still shows the same behavior whenever a remote host connects: it allows the connection, even shows it in netstat, but it doesn't seem to do anything. Anything typed is not parsed by the server and placed in the file, and typing exactly 138 chars and hitting Enter does nothing as well. This is intriguing.

Comment: So are you running the server in a debugger while you do this? How about some printf diagnostic output? It's going to be pretty hard to debug it "blind". Also, change the number of bytes you're reading to 1, to keep things as simple as possible. Print out the byte you've read after `read()` returns. See what happens. I would be very surprised if `read()` never returns, so you should be able to make *some* progress.

Comment: I had it print a message whenever a client connects. Then, it prints whatever the client sends. It turns out this may be an issue with PuTTY. The message the server displays is "ÿûÿû[newline]PuTTY". Naturally this wouldn't parse as it doesn't contain a colon separator.

Edit: oddly enough, the server should only accept 5 bytes, not enough for that particular message. (I couldn't change it to 1 without making a lot of odd changes.)

Comment: Ok, I don't know what you mean when you refer to a "colon separator" because you didn't post your code for `processServerMessage()` (I assume you're referring to something in there). Since these comments have gone on for a while now, and I think you've resolved the issue that this question actually refers to, I suggest you accept an answer for this question and open a new one that describes your next question.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your port is blocked by a firewall. Try telnet to the server via the 22580 port and see if it answers. If it does, then there's a problem between the server and your code. My guess is that it will timeout and not answer, so the problem is between your server and the network.

Most networks will block most ports, only opening port 80, 443, 25, 8080 and a few others.

telnet server.ip.address 22580

and see if it connects.

Comment: It may be the case that it's the network. I haven't ruled that out. However, I ran "iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22580 -j ACCEPT" and "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 22580 -j ACCEPT" on the server. So, I should be able to access it from the local network at least.

Comment: Many firewalls block traffic between nodes on the LAN - the telnet test will be a tell tale ;-)

Comment: @screennameless: Are you trying to access your server on the same Lan/Subnet?

Comment: Yes, only within the local network. I haven't tried opening it to the world yet.

Comment: @MattH alright, so I did telnet to the server, and it hung there doing nothing. I'm assuming this means it didn't reject it. But it doesn't do anything if I type in any data, so it's not connected to the server.

Comment: If it just hung there, then it didn't connect. You should get a telnet connected prompt if the server is able to connect on that port. Like try "telnet server 80" if you have a web server running on it.

Answer (score 0):

More information may be needed since there are many possible causes for this to fail.  If accessing (and nmapping) from the internet, you may need to "punch a hole" through your firewall configuration to allow access.  Otherwise tools like "netstat" and "tcpdump" on the listener host may provide more useful information.

Comment: Good tip. Netstat shows 
"tcp   0   0 192.168.1.10:22580   192.168.1.101:1941   ESTABLISHED"

And if you read my comment on Greg's post below, it shows that behavior.